# I need to get 100% code coverage

Tags: code-coverage

Can any one help me to How to get 100% code coverage for a class which consist multiple methods. My class having nearly 20 Methods and i want to cover code 100%. what are the steps i need to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want 100% code coverage you really need to write test methods that test  all of these 20 methods.

You can skip asserts if you just want the code coverage although I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write tests that cover each of the different methods.  The [Apex Testing](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/apex_testing) Trailhead module explains how to do this.